# Manipulate the url a webview gets before it starts loading

Tags: java, android, webview

I would like to add the current location as a request variable to URL's loaded in the webview so I can use this information on the page without reloads or extra requests.

I have a WebviewClient with shouldOverrideUrlLoading but this doesn't receive requests when they are passed using loadUrl. I read it's possible to intercept the requested URL using shouldInterceptRequest but I'm on API level 8 and don't really want to change this only for this.

Is there a way to manipulate the URL before it gets loaded by the webview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, change the `Url` before you call for `loadUrl`. You can create one function which modifies the `Url` and call it for `loadUrl` and in `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

```
public Url addLocationToUrl(Url url) {  
    Url newUrl = url;
    //do something with url
    return newUrl;
}   

loadUrl(addLocationToUrl(someUrl));

//and in your WebViewClient
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    mWebView.loadUrl(addLocationToUrl(someUrl));
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I did think of this but I have the location (at this time) only available in the webviewclient... Then again, maybe this is my clue to refactor my code a bit...

Comment: I just refactored my code to use your suggestion, accepted your answer since it's not only a good solution but also my code got better because of the refactoring ;)  Thanks!